# Google Cloud Messaging IOS registration using Cordova plugins

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

Google created a new way to register application using single location ([Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)), and we can use it to send messages to Android and IOS, Chrome.
I use Phonegap (Cordova) for making IOS/Andoid application, how can I register the application to use that service, I found an [old plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) for push notifications, but it's not using the new interface and registration of GCM.

So, any Idea about new plugin that can support IOS/Android registration to GCM?

Comment: Did you decided going that way after all? I've being implementing GCM AND APNS on my server side, altough using only one implementation would be mutch simpler. Please, share what you found.

Comment: I went that way but I still have a lot of problems in IOS, Android is good no problems with it.
I used "https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin"

Answer (score 1):

Check out [GCMPushPlugin](https://github.com/gonzaloaune/GCMPushPlugin)!

This is also currently being worked on at [PhoneGap Plugin Push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/) (a fork of the plugin you linked), [issue 115](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/115).

I think GCMPushPlugin would be your best bet for now, but considering that PhoneGap Plugin Push has ~40 more contributors, I'd keep my eyes open for updates, and see if it's worth switching over when they implement it.